# Is it possible to undelete a file in Gitpod?

Tags: gitpod

You won't believe this, but I genuinely am asking for a friend...

They've deleted a file (which they hadn't pushed to github) and have lost quite a bit of work. Not quite sure how it happened, but anyway. Is it possible that it's gone into some sort of recycling bin type folder? And if so, can it be recovered?

Can't find any docs online suggesting whether it's possible to recover files or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah, it seems that it is possible! There's a hidden Trash folder in the /workspace which you can view with `ls -a`. It contains a `files` directory with another directory inside with a UUID name. Deleted files can be found in there!

Comment: Glad, you were able to restore your file.